# using R to get results from API

Tags: r, json, api, httr

I make a call to an API by proving a latitude longitude as shown below

```
library(httr)
      
headers = c(
        'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
      )
      
body = '{
        "locations": [
          {"latitude": -37.916919, "longitude": 145.146892},
        ],
        "scenarios": ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"],
        "hazards": ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8", "v9"],
        "years": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
      }'
      
res <- VERB("POST", 
                  url = "https://xxx", body = body, add_headers(headers))
        
If I have a dataframe of lat,lon as shown below:
```

```
dat <-   

      structure(list(id = c(143L, 147L, 148L, 293L, 346L, 358L, 374L, 382L, 387L, 388L), 
                     latitude = c(-37.916919, -36.106951, -37.839613, -32.897738, -28.73769167, -27.8675, -28.064616, -28.016, -27.593, -27.648988), 
                     longitude = c(145.146892, 146.890143, 145.278376, 151.777484, 140.3534722, 139.6925, 139.538703, 139.692, 139.506, 139.458764)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                             "data.frame"))
```

How can I send each lat/lon in a for-loop to get the results back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making a function that takes `lat` and `long`, and use `apply` over the rows of your data.frame?

```
get_result <- function(lat,long) {
  headers = c('Content-Type' = 'application/json')
  
  body = paste0('{
    "locations": [
      {"latitude": ', lat, ', "longitude": ', long, '},
    ],
    "scenarios": ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"],
    "hazards": ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8", "v9"],
    "years": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
  }')
  
  VERB("POST", url = "https://xxx", body = body, add_headers(headers))
}

apply(dat,1,\(i) get_result(i[2], i[3]))
```